# Setting up a docker registry on EC2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-registry

I want to set up a private registry on an AWS ec2 instance, in such a way that I could securely push images, and our clients could securely pull them (but not push).

Right now I tried to do so with a self-signed certificate but I'm really confused about how it's supposed to work, and how to separate the push of images by me and the pull by the customers.

It would really help me if someone that has done something like that before could elaborate on how he did this.

Comment: Why not use ECR for this case?

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this you should deploy your registry behind a web server with authentication.

I can point you to an example that I followed long back for the same.
This is that [example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-four-%E2%80%94-secure-your-docker-registry-with-nginx)

Since you are in AWS infrastructure, I think you can go with ECR and easily handle access control.